# Change order status for backordered items in Woocommerce

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I am configuring a webshop using WordPress and WooCommerce. I have a plugin installed called [Woo Multi Order Creator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-multi-order-creator/). What is does is that whenever an order of more than 1 item is made, it divides the main order into multiple orders, one order per purchased item.

Now, what I want to do is to make it change the order status of each order, if the item in each order is containing meta key with the value "Backordered".

For example if product A and product B are purchased. Product A is in backorder, and therefore has 
`{$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key = 'Backordered'`
and product B would be in stock, and it would not have the metakey for backorder.

Now, the thing is that the plugin divides this order into two orders, one per purchased item. What I want it to do further, is to see if the items containted in each new order has the metakey for backorder, and if it has then change the order status to 'waiting', for every order.

Plugin code:

```
    <?php /*
Plugin Name: Woo Product Wise Multi Order Creator
Description: Create multiple orders in woocommerce product wise.
Plugin URI: http://www.thewpexperts.co.uk
Version: 2.0.0
Author: TheWPexperts 
Author URI: http://www.thewpexperts.com/ 
*/

 /*

    Copyright 2017  The WP Experts

    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2, as
    published by the Free Software Foundation.

    Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this
    software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software
    without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge,
    publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons
    to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

    The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or
    substantial portions of the Software.

    THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
    IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
    FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
    AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
    LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
    OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
    THE SOFTWARE.

*/ 
define( 'WOO_MULTI_ORDER_URL', plugins_url('/', __FILE__) );
define( 'WOO_MULTI_ORDER_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) );
if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_CPInstallCheck' ) ) {
    class WC_CPInstallCheck {
        static function install() {
            if ( !is_plugin_active('woocommerce/woocommerce.php')){
                deactivate_plugins(__FILE__);
                $error_message = __('This plugin requires <a href="http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/woocommerce/">WooCommerce</a>  plugins to be active!', 'woocommerce');
                die($error_message);
            }
        }
    }
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array('WC_CPInstallCheck', 'install') );
add_action('init','woo_multi_order_load_function');
function woo_multi_order_load_function() {
    $enableMultiOrder = get_option('enableMultiOrder'); 
    $customOrderPermit = get_option('customOrderPermit');   
    add_action('admin_menu', 'register_multi_order_setting_submenu',99);
    if($enableMultiOrder == 1){
        add_action('woocommerce_multiorder_checkout_before_order_info', 'destinationStep');
        add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'multi_order_generator', 10, 1 );
            if($customOrderPermit ==1){
            add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'woo_order_dates_checkout_field' ); 
            add_action( 'wp_head', 'date_picker_scripts' );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'checkout_update_delivery_meta' );
            add_filter("manage_edit-shop_order_columns", "woo_order_extra_columns");
            add_action("manage_posts_custom_column",  "woo_order_extra_columns_content");
            add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_sortable_columns', 'my_sortable_cake_column' );
        }
    }
} 
function your_plugin_settings_link($links) { 
  $settings_link = '<a href="admin.php?page=multi-order-setting">Settings</a>'; 
  array_unshift($links, $settings_link); 
  return $links; 
}
$plugin = plugin_basename(__FILE__); 
add_filter("plugin_action_links_$plugin", 'your_plugin_settings_link' );
function register_multi_order_setting_submenu() {
    add_submenu_page( 'woocommerce', 'Multi-order Setting', 'Multi-order Setting', 'manage_options', 'multi-order-setting', 'multi_order_setting' ); 
} 
function multi_order_setting(){
    include(WOO_MULTI_ORDER_DIR.'/admin/settings.php');
}
function date_picker_scripts() {
    $customOrderPermit = get_option('customOrderPermit');   
    if(is_page('checkout')){
      wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
      wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker', array( 'jquery' ) );
      wp_register_style('jquery-ui', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css');
      wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui' );         
    }
}
function checkout_update_delivery_meta( $order_id ) {
    $dateArray = array();
    $customOrderPermit = get_option('customOrderPermit');   
    $dayDifference = get_option('dayDifference');   
    $dt = date('d/m/y', strtotime("+".$dayDifference." days"));
    if ( count($_POST['customDatePicker'])>0) {
        foreach($_POST['customDatePicker'] as $customDatePicker){
            if(!empty($customDatePicker)){
                $dateArray[]  = $customDatePicker;
            }else{
                $dateArray[]  = $dt;
            }
        }
    }
    $dateValue = join( ', ', $dateArray ); 
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Delivery_Dates', $dateValue);
} 
function woo_order_dates_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
    global $woocommerce,$orderRate;
    $customOrderPermit = get_option('customOrderPermit');   
    $dayDifference = get_option('dayDifference');   
    $dt = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+".$dayDifference." days"));
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
        $_product = $values['data']->post; 
        $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
        echo "<b>".$_product->post_title."</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        echo '<input type="text" class="deliveryDate" id="datepicker'.$_product->ID.'" name="customDatePicker[]" placeholder="Choose dates">'; ?> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery("#datepicker<?php echo $_product->ID;?>").datepicker({ 
                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', 
                    minDate: new Date('<?php echo $dt; ?>'),
                });
            });
        </script>   
        <?php 
    } 
}
function multi_order_generator($order_id) {
    $customOrderPermit = get_option('customOrderPermit');   
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();
    $count =0;
    $productID = array();
    $productQty = array();
    $deliveryDate = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'Delivery_Dates',true);
    $dateArray = explode(',',$deliveryDate);
    foreach($items as $order_item_id => $item){
        if($count >0){
            $productName = get_the_title($item['product_id']);
            $orderValueID = createNewOrderAndRecordPayment($order_id);
            addProductWithOrder($orderValueID,$item['product_id'],$item['qty']);
            if($customOrderPermit == 1){
                    update_post_meta($orderValueID,'_Delivery_Date',$dateArray[$count]);
            }
            wc_delete_order_item($order_item_id);
        }else{
            if($customOrderPermit == 1){
                    update_post_meta($order_id,'_Delivery_Date',$dateArray[0]);
            }
        }
        $count++;
    }
}
function addProductWithOrder($orderID,$productID,$productQty){
    $ProOrderItem = new WC_Order($orderID); 
    $ProOrderItem->add_product(get_product($productID),$productQty); 
}
function createNewOrderAndRecordPayment($orderID) {
    global $wpdb;
    global $woocommerce;
    $original_order = new WC_Order($orderID);
    $currentUser = wp_get_current_user();
    //1 Create Order
    $order_data =  array(
        'post_type'     => 'shop_order',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'ping_status'   => 'closed',
        'post_author'   => $currentUser->ID, 
        'post_excerpt' => $original_order->customer_message, 
        'post_password' => uniqid( 'order_' )   // Protects the post just in case
    );
    $order_id = wp_insert_post( $order_data, true );
    if ( is_wp_error( $order_id ) ){
        $msg = "Unable to create order:" . $order_id->get_error_message();;
        throw new Exception( $msg );
    } else {
        $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
        //2 Update Order Header 
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_shipping', get_post_meta($orderID, '_order_shipping', true) );
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_discount', get_post_meta($orderID, '_order_discount', true) );
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_cart_discount',  get_post_meta($orderID, '_cart_discount', true) );
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_tax',              get_post_meta($orderID, '_order_tax', true) );
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_shipping_tax',     get_post_meta($orderID, '_order_shipping_tax', true) );
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_total',            get_post_meta($orderID, '_order_total', true) );

        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_key',              'wc_' . apply_filters('woocommerce_generate_order_key', uniqid('order_') ) );
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_customer_user',          get_post_meta($orderID, '_customer_user', true) );
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_currency',         get_post_meta($orderID, '_order_currency', true) );
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_prices_include_tax',     get_post_meta($orderID, '_prices_include_tax', true) );
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_customer_ip_address',    get_post_meta($orderID, '_customer_ip_address', true) );
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_customer_user_agent',    get_post_meta($orderID, '_customer_user_agent', true) );

        //3 Add Billing Fields

        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_city',           get_post_meta($orderID, '_billing_city', true));
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_state',          get_post_meta($orderID, '_billing_state', true));
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_postcode',       get_post_meta($orderID, '_billing_postcode', true));
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_email',          get_post_meta($orderID, '_billing_email', true));
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_phone',          get_post_meta($orderID, '_billing_phone', true));
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_address_1',      get_post_meta($orderID, '_billing_address_1', true));
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_address_2',      get_post_meta($orderID, '_billing_address_2', true));
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_country',        get_post_meta($orderID, '_billing_country', true));
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_first_name',     get_post_meta($orderID, '_billing_first_name', true));
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_last_name',      get_post_meta($orderID, '_billing_last_name', true));
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_company',        get_post_meta($orderID, '_billing_company', true));

        //4 Add Shipping Fields

        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_shipping_country',       get_post_meta($orderID, '_shipping_country', true));
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_shipping_first_name',    get_post_meta($orderID, '_shipping_first_name', true));
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_shipping_last_name',     get_post_meta($orderID, '_shipping_last_name', true));
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_shipping_company',       get_post_meta($orderID, '_shipping_company', true));
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_shipping_address_1',     get_post_meta($orderID, '_shipping_address_1', true));
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_shipping_address_2',     get_post_meta($orderID, '_shipping_address_2', true));
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_shipping_city',          get_post_meta($orderID, '_shipping_city', true));
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_shipping_state',         get_post_meta($orderID, '_shipping_state', true));
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_shipping_postcode',      get_post_meta($orderID, '_shipping_postcode', true));

        //6 Copy shipping items and shipping item meta from original order
        $original_order_shipping_items = $original_order->get_items('shipping');
        foreach ( $original_order_shipping_items as $original_order_shipping_item ) {
            $item_id = wc_add_order_item( $order_id, array(
                'order_item_name'       => $original_order_shipping_item['name'],
                'order_item_type'       => 'shipping'
            ) );
            if ( $item_id ) {
                wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'method_id', $original_order_shipping_item['method_id'] );
                wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'cost', wc_format_decimal( $original_order_shipping_item['cost'] ) );
            }
        }

        // Store coupons
        $original_order_coupons = $original_order->get_items('coupon');
        foreach ( $original_order_coupons as $original_order_coupon ) {
            $item_id = wc_add_order_item( $order_id, array(
                'order_item_name'       => $original_order_coupon['name'],
                'order_item_type'       => 'coupon'
            ) );
            // Add line item meta
            if ( $item_id ) {
                wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'discount_amount', $original_order_coupon['discount_amount'] );
            }
        }

        //Payment Info
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_payment_method',         get_post_meta($orderID, '_payment_method', true) );
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_payment_method_title',   get_post_meta($orderID, '_payment_method_title', true) );
        update_post_meta( $order->id, 'Transaction ID',         get_post_meta($orderID, 'Transaction ID', true) );
        $order->payment_complete();

        //6 Set Order Status to processing to trigger initial emails to end user and vendor
        $order->update_status('processing'); 
    }
    return $order_id;
}
function woo_order_extra_columns($columns)
{
   $newcolumns = array(
        "cb"            => "<input type  = \"checkbox\" />",
        "delivery"    => esc_html__('Delivery', 'woocommerce'),
    );
    $columns = array_merge($newcolumns, $columns);
    return $columns;
}
function woo_order_extra_columns_content($column)
{
    global $post;
    $order_id = $post->ID;
    switch ($column)
    {
        case "delivery":
        $daliveryDate = get_post_meta($order_id,'_Delivery_Date',true);
        if ( empty( $daliveryDate ) )
                echo __( '-' );
        else
            printf( __( '%s' ), $daliveryDate );
        break;
    }
}

function my_sortable_cake_column( $columns ) {
$columns['delivery'] = 'delivery';
    return $columns;
}
```

It changes the order status to processing at line 253.

I'm guessing that it is around here that a bit of code should be added to make it change order status to waiting instead, if the item in the order has the metakey for backorder.

I hope that someone with more expertise than my very limited knowlegde can come to my assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a hooked function that is triggered when orders get a "processing" status.

Inside the function we look for order items that are "Backordered" with a simple and light SQL query from the order ID.

If a "Backordered" item is found, we change the order status to "on-hold" (the correct order status for your case).

The code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'pending_back_orders_to_on_hold', 60, 2 );
function pending_back_orders_to_on_hold( $order_id, $order ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // The SQL query for Order items in backorder
    $results = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT woim.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as woim
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as woi ON woim.order_item_id = woi.order_item_id
        WHERE woi.order_id = '$order_id' AND woim.meta_key = 'Backordered'
    " );
    
    // If an item is 'Backordered' we change the order status to "on-hold"
    if(reset($results) > 0)
        $order->update_status('on-hold');
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.

---

> **Update** *(related to your comment)*

If you want to change the code inside the plugin for that purpose, you will replace line 253:

```
$order->update_status('processing');
```

By the following code:

```
$line_item_ids = array_keys( $order->get_items() );
$backordered = wc_get_order_item_meta( reset($line_item_ids), 'Backordered', true );
$changed_status = $backorders > 0 ? 'on-hold' : 'processing';
$order->update_status( $changed_status );
```

> It should work, **but this is not a good practice.**

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out! There is one problem however. It doesn't work with the plugin I have installed. If I make an order, it puts that first order on hold, and creates a new order from each item there is more than one. That is, your snippet works before the plugin has divided the orders into seperate ones.
I suppose another hook could be used? Something that changes orders to on hold at a later point in time, after the plugin has done it's job?

Comment: @clauden No other hooks!  `woocommerce_order_status_processing` hook is just triggered when your plugin uses:  `$order->update_status('processing');`

Comment: Okay. It just does not work the way it should. If I purchase 2 backordered items and 1 item in stock, it does not consistently change the order status to on hold, for each order with a backordered item in it. I have tried integrating your code directly into the plugin code, but without success.

Do you think you would be able to integrate your snippet into the plugin code, so that it might work as intended? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @clauden Keep trying as this is the good track… you could also try to ask authors to add a hook there, as it will allow to change the behavior with ease.